# How do I make ImageMagick work on Visual studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, imagemagick

I tried to install ImageMagick so I could turn some pictures into gif in C programing.
I installed it succesfully (checked the c/c++ headers box and everything) but I still can not use it in my code. I assumed it is a problom with visual studio (2019) needing of adjustments but I'm not sure.
I downloded from this link: https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php for windows (The latest version).

this is what I tried (just includes):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wand/MagickWand.h>
```

the error was: cannot open source file wand/MagickWand.h.

*note: sorry about my english if it's bad...
I'll be happy for help with that, thanks in advance for the responders.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show us your code, and the exact error you are getting? Please add them as text in code blocks rather than as images. You can learn more about formatting your question here: [Learn more about formatting...](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: Just a rant, but be aware that if you write any code using imagemagick api, you'll have to rewrite it next year. And then the year after that. And then the year after that. Not saying it randomly: I have a student code that I've been using for 2 decades. And I am litteraly forced to rewrite parts each year (well till this year: I finally took the time to port it using FreeImage), because of API changes. They just don't understand that updating the library (implementation) and updating the API (the interface) is not the same, and that the latter should be avoided at all cost for a library.